# Avoid race condition using std::mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I am dealing with the multi-threading project with C++ and I doubt about std::mutex

Let's assume that I have a stack.

```
#include <exception>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <stack>
struct empty_stack: std::exception
{
    const char* what() const throw();
};
template<typename T>
class threadsafe_stack
{
private:
    std::stack<T> data;
    mutable std::mutex m;
public:
    threadsafe_stack(){}
    threadsafe_stack(const threadsafe_stack& other)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(other.m);
        data=other.data;
    }
    threadsafe_stack& operator=(const threadsafe_stack&) = delete;
    void push(T new_value)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
        data.push(new_value);
    }
    std::shared_ptr<T> pop()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
        if(data.empty()) throw empty_stack();
        std::shared_ptr<T> const res(std::make_shared<T>(data.top()));
        data.pop();
        return res;
    }
    void pop(T& value)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
        if(data.empty()) throw empty_stack();
        value=data.top();
        data.pop();
    }
    bool empty() const
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
        return data.empty();
    }
};
```

Someone said that using this stack can avoid race condition. However I think that problem here is that mutex aka mutual exclusion here only ensure for individual function not together. For example, I can have the threads call push and pop. Those function still have problem of race condition.

For example:

```
threadsafe_stack st; //global varibale for simple

void fun1(threadsafe_stack st)
{

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    st.push(t);
    t = st.pop();
    //
}

void fun2(threadsafe_stack st)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    T t,t2;
    t = st.pop();
    // Do big things
    st.push(t2);

    //
}
```

If a thread fun1 and fun2 call the same stack (global variable for simple). So it can be a race condition(?)

I have only solution I can think is using some kind of atomic transaction means instead of calling directly push(), pop(), empty(), I call them via a function with a "function pointer" to those function and with only one mutex.

For example:

```
#define PUSH    0
#define POP     1
#define EMPTY   2

changeStack(int kindOfFunction, T* input, bool* isEmpty)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    switch(kindOfFunction){
        case PUSH:
            push(input);
            break;
        case POP:
            input = pop();
            break;
        case EMPTY:
            isEmpty = empty();
            break;          
    }
}
```

Is my solution good? Or I just overthinking and the first solution my friend told me is good enough? Are there any other solution for this? The solution can avoid "atomic transaction" like I suggest.

Comment: Why you think that if you call pop/push from threads, there will be a race condition? Thread A calls push and block mutex, thread B calls pop and wait till mutex will be unblocked by push.

Comment: You are trying to solve a non-problem. "mutex aka mutual exclusion here only ensure for individual function not together." --- this is the faulty assumption.

Comment: The way you have written `fun1` and `fun2`, there can never be a race condition --- you are passing the objects by value (i.e., copy), not by reference.

Answer (score 4):

A given mutex is a single lock and can be held by a single thread at any one time.

If a thread (T1) is holding the lock on a given object in `push()` another thread (T2) cannot acquire it in `pop()` and will be blocked until T1 releases it. At that point of release T2 (or another thread also blocked by the same mutex) will be unblocked and allowed to proceed.

**You do not need to do all the locking and unlocking in one member.**

The point where you may still be introducing a *race condition* is constructs like this if they appear in consumer code:

```
if(!stack.empty()){
    auto item=stack.pop();//Guaranteed?
}
```

If another thread T2 enters `pop()` after thread T1 enters `empty()` (above) and gets blocked waiting on the mutex then the `pop()` in T1 may fail because T2 'got there first'. Any number of actions might take place between the end of `empty()` and the start of `pop()` in that snippet unless other synchronization is handling it.

In this case you should imagine T1 & T2 literally *racing* to `pop()` though of course they may be racing to different members and still invalidate each other...

If you want to build code like that you usually have to then add further *atomic* member functions like `try_pop()` which returns (say) an empty `std::shared_ptr<>` if the stack is empty.

I hope this sentence isn't confusing:

> Locking the object mutex inside member functions avoids race
>   conditions *between* calls to those member functions but not *in
>   between* calls to those member functions.

The best way to solve that is by adding 'composite' functions that are doing the job of more than one 'logical' operation. That tends to go against good class design in which you design a logical set of minimal operations and the consuming code combines them.

The alternative is to allow the consuming code access to the mutex. For example expose `void lock() const;` and `void unlock() cont;` members. That is usually not preferred because (a) it becomes very easy for consumer code to create deadlocks and (b) you either use a recursive lock (with its overhead) or double up member functions again:

```
void pop(); //Self locking version...
void pop_prelocked(); //Caller must hold object mutex or program invalidated.
```

Whether you expose them as `public` or `protected` or not that would make `try_pop()` look something like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<T> try_pop(){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);
    if(empty_prelocked()){
        return std::shared_ptr<T>();
    }
    return pop_prelocked();
}
```

Adding a mutex and acquiring it at the start of each member is only the start of the story...

Footnote: Hopefully that explains **mu**tual **ex**lusion (**mut****ex**). There's a whole other topic round *memory barriers* lurking below the surface here but if you use mutexes in this way you can treat that as an implementation detail for now...

Comment: Thank you. I understand better now.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand something. You don't need that `changeStack` function.

If you forget about `lock_guard`, here's what it looks like (with `lock_guard`, the code does the same, but `lock_guard` makes it convenient: makes unlock automatic):

```
push() {
  m.lock();
  // do the push
  m.unlock();
}

pop() {
  m.lock();
  // do the pop
  m.unlock();
}
```

When `push` is called, mutex will be locked. Now, imagine, that on other thread, there is `pop` called. `pop` tries to lock the mutex, but it cannot lock it, because `push` already locked it. So it has to wait for `push` to unlock the mutex. When `push` unlocks the mutex, then `pop` can lock it.

So, in short, it is `std::mutex` which does the mutual exclusion, not the `lock_guard`.

Comment: Just a question... Isn't `lock_guard` better/safer than using `lock` and `unlock` in the sense that if `push` or `pop` throws, at least the destructor of `lock_guard` will unlock the mutex automatically?

Comment: @ArdaAytekin: yes, `lock_guard` is preferred. I made this example this way, because it was easier to explain. It is easier to see what's going on (no need to explain the "invisible" unlock when the function returns)